# Why will my error message not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a error set up, if a user does not select if they are male female. The error message should be, Please select your gender. I am not getting that message, I am getting the regular message I would if they selected there gender, but im getting it in read text. My only red text is for errors, so im not getting whats going on. my code is 100 lines long so i will just post the part with the error message in it, and will post a fiddle.

```
if (isNaN(total)) {
    msg = 'Input three numbers, please...';

} else if ($genderRadio.filter(':checked').length === 0) {
    msg = 'Please select your gender....';    
} else {
    $output.removeClass('error');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7xM2f/46/

Comment: Please check declaration of the variable on top of the code , var $output = $('#output');
var $output1 = $('#output1');
genderRadio = $('input[name=gender]');

Comment: genderRadio change by var $genderRadio

Comment: *many* problems, please test each part separately.

Comment: So many problem in code Please first of all check you variables declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the `total` conditions at the bottom, it is overriding the error messages

you need something like

```
    if(!msg){     
        if (total < 10) {
            msg = "should be higher...";
        } else if (total > 20) {
            msg = "super good ...";
        } else {
            msg = "not bad.";
        }
    }
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqUcb/)

Comment: interesting. Question, im just wondering, if put put the if's.. that's good, not bad... first, and put the if's for if gender box is not selected last would it have worked then? Does it just take the last msg to the outbox?

Comment: tried it if i put the if's for total first, then the if's for the gender it works  http://jsfiddle.net/7xM2f/48/

Answer (score 0):

Please check you code

```
 var $genderRadio = $('input[name=gender]');
```

Please use this code for condition  :

```
else if ($('input[name=gender]:checked').val()==undefined)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use else-if so and sort the order with respect to priority so the most prior condition occurs first.

try this:

```
    if (isNaN(total)) {
        msg = 'Input three numbers, please...';    
    } else if ($genderRadio.filter(':checked').length === 0) {
        msg = 'Please select your gender....';
    } else if {
        $output.removeClass('error');
    } else if (total < 10) {
            msg = "bad need a lot of work...";
    } else if (total > 20) {
        msg = "super super good...";
    } else {
        msg = "your with in the average.";
    }

    $output.text(msg);
    $output1.text(msg1);
```